# Proving a subspace is a closed subspace of $C[0,1]$ with inner product?

Tags: analysis, inner-products

Consider the inner product space of continuously differentiable functions $C^1 [0,1]$ with the inner product: $$<f,g> = \int^1_0 f(x) \overline{g(x)} dx + \int^1_0 f'(x) \overline{g'(x)} dx$$

In part one of the question we are asked to show that $<f,\cosh(x)> = f(1)\sinh(1)$ for any $f \in C^1[0,1]$ . I have done this.

In part 2 we are asked to use this to show that the subspace $\{f \in C^1[0,1]: f(1) = 0\}$ is a closed subspace of $C^1[0,1]$. This is where I really need help.

I want to show the compliment of the subspace, call it say $A^c$ is open. That is $A^c = \{f \in C^[0,1]: f(1) \neq 0\}$ is open. I believe this means that for every $f \in A^c$ there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(f) = \{g \in C^1 [0,1]: <f-g,f-g> < \epsilon\}$

But I firstly dont know if I am going about this in the right way? If so can I have some hints for the next steps? I have not tried to prove something like this before in terms of functions. Also I don't know where the relevance of part a) comes in. Are we evaluating in terms of $f(1)g(1)$ ? Thanks

Comment: Use sequences, it is usually a more concrete approach when working in function spaces.

Comment: Okay so I can say that $A$ is closed if and only if for every convergent sequence $(x_n) \subset A$ $$x=lim x_n \in A$. Then $lim f_n \to f ||f_n - f|| = lim f_n \to f \sqrt{\int^1_0 (f_n(x)-f(x)) \overline{f_n(x) - f(x)} dx + \int^1_0 (f_n(x)-f(x))' \overline{(f_n(x)-f(x))'} dx}$$

Comment: sorry that comment messed up...
Okay so I can say that A is closed if and only if for every convergent sequence $(x_n) \subset A$, $x=lim x_n \in A$. Then $$lim f_n \to f ||f_n - f||$$ $$ =lim f_n \to f \sqrt{\int^1_0 (f_n(x)-f(x)) \overline{f_n(x) - f(x)} dx + \int^1_0 (f_n(x)-f(x))' \overline{(f_n(x)-f(x))'} dx}$$

However this equation looks really horrible and messy, what would my next step be?